# I want to read the buffer of a audio.wav file and save it to a another file in swift

Tags: ios, audio, buffer, swift3, watchos-3

I recorded a audio.wav file with `presentAudioRecorderController` from my watchos3 and now i want to read it in my iOS app.
I want the buffer float data of this file.

how can i do that ?